# plink output redirection fails

Tags: windows, ssh, plink

I am trying to execute a command file in a remote host.

```
plink -ssh -P 22 -l abc -pw abc 192.168.44.4 -m "C:\Users\soni\Desktop\cmd.txt" > "C:\Users\soni\Desktop\out.txt"
```

However this works only if the output is not redirected to file. If I redirect the command output to a file as show in the above command, it results in this error.

```
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do not execute the command?

Comment: Wrong forum, and probably duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/121304/how-to-make-git-to-work-with-pagentputty-on-windows